# Uploading Files to Dropbox using Dropbox API V2 + Corodva

Tags: javascript, cordova, dropbox-api

Has anyone been able to upload files to Dropbox using Javascript SDK for Dropbox [(Link to Dropbox javascript SDK)](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js) API V2 in Cordova Application? I had a look at the Dropbox-sdk.js file  for method to upload files but all the methods require content of the file we want to upload to dropbox [More about Upload methods here](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesUpload__anchor). How do we provide the content of the files?
The [examples from the Javascript Sdk](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/tree/master/examples) use input type file element to get the files to be uploaded to the Dropbox. But in case of Cordova how to do it? How can we pass the contents of the file?

Below is my code to upload File to Dropbox but when I try to open the uploaded file it show pdf file with no contents.

```
 function uploadFile(tmpStrListStr)
    {
        var tmpStrList = "";
        var uploadSuccess = false;
        tmpStrList = tmpStrListStr.substring(0, tmpStrListStr.length-1).split(",");
        istrue = true;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < tmpStrList.length; i++)
         {  
         var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+'/Test/Logs/'+tmpStrList[i] + '.pdf';
         window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function (fileEntry) {

          fileEntry.file(function(file) {
              var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function(e) {

                var ACCESS_TOKEN = localStorage.accessToken;            
                var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });              

                var fileCommitInfo = {};
                fileCommitInfo.contents = reader.result;
                fileCommitInfo.path = '/' + fileEntry.name;
                fileCommitInfo.mode = { '.tag': 'overwrite' };
                fileCommitInfo.autorename = true;
                fileCommitInfo.mute = true;

                dbx.filesUpload(fileCommitInfo)
                  .then(function(response) {
                      alert(response);

                  })
                  .catch(function(errr) {
                    console.log(errr);
                  });

              }

              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });

      }, function (e) {
            console.log("FileSystem Error");
            console.dir(e);
        });

       }

    }
```

Is there any other way to implement the Dropbox feature(API V2) for Cordova Applications without using Javascript SDK?

Is there anyone in this whole world who can tell me how to upload the files to Dropbox using Javascript SDK V2?

Comment: It looks like you are filling in the correct parameters in your [`FilesCommitInfo`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/global.html#FilesCommitInfo). Can  you check what the value of `reader.result` is?

Comment: Reader.result contains the file's data as a base64 encoded string.

Comment: It shouldn't be base64 encoded, but providing a string there should be fine in general, so getting an empty file isn't expected. Are you getting `response` or `errr`? Please share the output of whichever you do get.

Comment: @Nikhil if you found a solution, please post it here. TIA!

Comment: @Devashish Sorry about the delay in response....! I have added answer below. have a look..

Comment: @Devashish Did the code work for you?

Comment: @Nikhil I still have to test it buddy. I will surely let you know if it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the contents of a file used XMLHttpRequest. From the response, created a blob object and then set it to contents parameter of the FilesUpload method.

```
function UploadNewFile() {

         var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();         
            rawFile.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            rawFile.open("GET", "Your file Path Here", true);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {                       
                        var blobObj = new Blob([rawFile.response],{ type: 'application/pdf',endings: 'native' });
                        dbx = new Dropbox({accessToken: "Your Access Token"});
                        if (dbx != null) {                      
                            dbx.filesUpload({
                                path:'/' + "File Name Here"+ '.pdf',
                                contents: blobObj,
                                mode: 'overwrite',
                                mute: true
                            }).then(function (response) {
                                 var showmsg = "File Upload Complete";
                                 reset();
                                 alertify.alert(showmsg, function (e)
                                    {
                                       if (e)
                                       {
                                        //Code to be executed after your files are successfully uploaded to Dropbox.
                                       }
                                   });

                                }

                            }).catch(function (error) {
                                var showmsg = "Error saving file to your Dropbox!";
                                reset();    
                                     alertify.alert(showmsg);
                            });                     
                        };

                    }
              }           
        }
         rawFile.send(null);
    }
```

Reference:[What is blob?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)